# Changing PHP version wamp

Tags: php, wamp, version

I've been asked to change my PHP environement locally for a project so that go from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 (or higher).
So I've changed the PHP version of my wamp but it doesn't show any error it just says :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'd like to know how can I display errors so that I can start to change stuff in the code.

Configuration of php.ini :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you check the end of Apache's (error) logfile? You should also enable `display_errors = on` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Lot of missing information. When do you see this? On restarting the server or when running a project? How did you manage to change the version?

Comment: This tutorial covers everything from scratch to end.. 
https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/

Comment: @Damocles wher could i find this file ?

Comment: @vivek_23 whoops my bad, i first changed the version of PHP then runned the project and this error appeared

Comment: @Jaymin okay thanks i'll take a look a it

Comment: @DilanHassan Can you confirm if it's successfully changed with `phpinfo();`?

Comment: @vivek_23 No i haven't changed ```phpinfo()``` where can i find it ?

Comment: @DilanHassan Make a simple `php` file in `www` folder and place `phpinfo();` and check in browser what PHP version it shows you ?

Comment: @vivek_23 it says that i'm on PHP 7.3.1

Comment: @DilanHassan Looks ok, restart the server just to be extra sure. Also, are you running a project based on some framework? Is it in `production` mode in `index.php` file?

Comment: @vivek_23 Restarted.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes i'm using cakephp and i don't think that's it's in production mode

Comment: @DilanHassan Then check the logs present in `apache\logs` folder for error messages(this of XAMPP, similar could be for WAMP).

Comment: @DilanHassan Also change environment variable path in windows for `php.exe`.

Comment: @vivek_23 where do i change this variable ?

Comment: @DilanHassan Are you on windows OS?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes i am

Comment: @DilanHassan [See here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) on how to change environment variable.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks a lot for your help my project is now running on PHP7